# Encountering error while running jupyter themes in anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed `jupyter` themes package by `conda` and even by `pip`, but when I want to change my Jupyter Notebook theme running this code:

```
!jt ...
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\Scripts\jt-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterthemes\__init__.py", line 290, in main
    install_theme(
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterthemes\__init__.py", line 103, in install_theme
    style_css = stylefx.less_to_css(style_less)
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterthemes\stylefx.py", line 75, in less_to_css
    style_css = lesscpy.compile(tempfile)
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lesscpy\__init__.py", line 18, in compile
    p.parse(file=file)
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lesscpy\lessc\parser.py", line 156, in parse
    self.post_parse()
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lesscpy\lessc\parser.py", line 171, in post_parse
    self.result = list(utility.flatten(out))
  File "C:\Users\erfan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lesscpy\lessc\utility.py", line 28, in flatten
    if isinstance(elm, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(elm, string_types):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'
```

Thanks for helping!

I have reinstalled `jupyter theme` package but it didn't work. I have even reinstalled the whole Anaconda.

Comment: Did you completely uninstall before re-installing? On what system are you working?

Comment: I'm win 11. Yes I have uninstalled anaconda using your uninstaller and then installed it again but anything didn't change.

Comment: Have you created a file called `collections.py` in the same folder your notebook runs in?

Comment: I haven't done anything by myself. I just installed anaconda and then I ran this command to install tensorflow. Should I have created this python file?